# Does word ordering affect monolingual alignment success

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, word2vec

I spent some time reading about both Word2Vec embeddings and alignment between different embeddings (for instance [vecmap](https://aclanthology.org/P18-1073/)) and was wondering whether there is any significance to the word ordering of the different languages and how well the alignment can be made.

I haven't found much research in this topic (found quite a bit regarding word ordering in other cross-lingual tasks) and was wondering if the typological feature actually has an effect. Have you seen any papers in the matter?

Answer (score 1):

Is it just about Word2Vec or NLP in general?

About Word2Vec, there is this paper that might be interesting:

**Relevant Word Order Vectorization for
Improved Natural Language Processing in
Electronic Healthcare Records**

https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1812/1812.02627.pdf

Then, other ones could answer your question, but not directly. Maybe they could give some interesting clues:

**Towards Structure-aware Paraphrase Identification with Phrase
Alignment Using Sentence Encoders**

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.05302.pdf

**Tag-Aware Document Representation for Research Paper
Recommendation**

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2209.03660.pdf

Please let me know if it helps, I may have other interesting papers.

Comment: Does it answer your question? If not, please let me know.